# Page break at 5 units

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[page](http://jsfiddle.net/S2rnm/846/) consists of 3 blocks. on a variety of mobile devices is changing the page template.

please help in this way are 5 blocks.

the problem that the bootstrap consists of 12 columns. 12 is not divisible by 5

html:

```
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box_outer">
                    <article class="box">
                        <span class="pic corners5"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/news_pics/news-pic.jpg" width="305" height="134" alt=""></span>

                        <p>We have recently completed beatiful website for  a luxury hair beauty y completed for  a luxury hair beauty boutique Salon Studio. The website is ...</p>
                    </article>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box_outer">
                    <article class="box">
                        <span class="pic corners5"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/news_pics/news-pic.jpg" width="305" height="134" alt=""></span>

                        <p>We have recently completed beatiful website for  a luxury hair beauty boutique Smpleted beatiful website for  a luxury hair beauty boutique Salon Studio. The website is ...</p>
                    </article>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box_outer">
                    <article class="box">
                        <span class="pic corners5"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/news_pics/news-pic.jpg" width="305" height="134" alt=""></span>

                        <p>We have recently completed beatiful website for  a luxury hair beauty boutique Salon Studio. The website is ...</p>
                    </article>
                </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want to break it in 5 rather than 3 as it's breaking in cozy space

Comment: Not quite sure I understand.. If your going for 5 blocks then you have to make a `fluid-row` with `5 span divs` each div would have to be `span 2` in length except for the last which would be `span 4` to complete the row.